# Datatables broken my sort

Tags: datatables

Im having funny issue with bootstrap datatables.

Its changing my sort option (based on status value of database rows) to own ascending value of first column.

Anybody know the way to disable sort after generating datatables layout.

Regards to all

Comment: "bSort": false,   http://jsfiddle.net/bbLjzspf/7277/

Comment: thx its worked with quotes